# Docker Container cant connect to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, docker, mysql-workbench

I have a MySQL instance running in a docker container, available on my host system at port 3333. I already tested the connection via the MySQL workbench to verify, that the user I created is able to login to the SQL server.

I also have a wikijs [(installation guide found here)](https://docs.requarks.io/install/docker) instance running in a container.
I have provided all the required environment variables, including the information of the user I already tested, but the container always says that the connection was refused.

Does anybody have an idea on what the problem is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No information does not help solving your problem but a wild guess:

By default docker containers are joining a virtual network separate from host named `bridge`.

You can't reach host by `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`, because this is pointing to your docker container itself. To reach host directly either let container use hosts IP by `--network=host` (with some disadvantages) or use `host.docker.internal` as DNS-Name instead of an IP.

BUT you should not take the way over host, connect directly to the mySQL-container by using the alias or IP or the container. You'll get that by `docker inspect <containername>`. No need to map ports then..

Comment: Thank you very much, the --network=host fixed the issue

Answer (score -4):

Kindly try adjusting the port to 3306 and see if it works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).